# How do i compile MPI programs

Tags: compiler-errors, mpi

I try to run a parallel code on MPI using " mpirun -np 4 ./code.c " and I  get this message:

> Open MPI tried to fork a new process via the "execve" system call but
> failed.  Open MPI checks many things before attempting to launch a
> child process, but nothing is perfect. This error may be indicative of
> another problem on the target host, or even something as silly as
> having specified a directory for your application. Your job will now
> abort.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `code.c` contain your code?

Answer (score 0):

You must compile your code before you can run it using `mpirun`.
To compile your code:

```
mpicc code.c -o code
```

Make sure you install a compiler to do this. You can use [Open MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v4.0/).
Then, run it using:

```
mpirun -np 4 code
```

You can find a great tutorial [here](https://mpitutorial.com/).